# ARIES KVL, why we always insert into 1st_page

Tags: algorithm, database, recovery, aries

I am learning your paper ARIES/KVL[1], from the paper, The B+tree structure looks like:

> ```
>                     ------------------------------------
>                     |  p0  |  k0  |  p1  |  k1  |  p2  |
>                     ------------------------------------
>                      /                \                                      
>                     /                  \                                   
>                    /                    \                                  
>                   /                      \                                 
>                  /                        \                               
>              --------      <-----      --------
>              |  c0  |                  |  c1  |
>              --------      ----->      --------
> ```

From the Search pseudo codes, Fetch, Insert, and Delete never see in progrss SMO, because of restart search after completion of SMO.  Once, we entered Insert Procedure, the following conditions are held:

1. x latch 1st_leaf,
2. No SMO which involved 1st_leaf is in progress.
3. The highest key of 1st_leaf < separated key
4. The keys of 2nd_leaf >= separated key
5. The keys of 1st_leaf < the keys of 2nd_leaf
6. The to-be-inserted-key < separated key.

For example, given the above pictue, when we insert a key in c0, then

1. c0 is x latched
2. No SMO which involved c0 is in progress.
3. The highest key of c0 < k0
4. The keys of c1 >= k0
5. The keys of c0 < the keys of c1
6. The to-be-inserted-key < k0.

The following codes are excerpted from [1], and I remove the un-related parts of my question.

```
/*No Space for Insert of Key*/
.....    
/* No Need to Lock Next Key */
.....

/* Insert Key Value NOT Already in 1st_Leaf */
IF No Higher Key Value in 1st_Leaf AND 2nd_leaf Exists THEN
  S Latch 2nd_Leaf /* while Holding X Latch on 1st_Leaf */
  IF 2nd_Leaf is Empty THEN              /*Page Delete in Progress-Wait for it to be Over*/
    Unlatch 1st_Leaf and 2nd_Leaf
    S Latch Tree for Instant-Duration
    Unwind Recursion as far as Necessary Based on Noted Page VNs and Go Down Again
  ELSE                                                     /* 2nd_Leaf is NOT Empty */
    IF Insert Key Value found in 2nd_Leaf THEN             /* This Can't be a Unique Index */
      IX Lock Insert Key Value for Commit Duration
      Unlatch 2nd_Leaf, Insert Key in 1st_Leaf, Log, Unlatch 1st_leaf and Return
    ELSE Next Key Value := First Key Value in 2nd_Leaf
ELSE
  IF No Higher Key Value in 1st_Leaf THEN Next Key Value := End_Of_file
  ELSE Next Key Value := Higher Key Value in 1st_Leaf

IX Lock Next Key Value for Instant Duration

/*Insert Key into 1st_leaf*/
.....
```

**Q1:** Why we can find a Insert Key Value in 2nd_leaf? **My guess is** there are many updates caused by other transactions during the time **from releasing latch of parent of 1st_leaf and trying to s_latch 2nd_leaf**, and hence a to-be-inserted-key is found in 2nd_leaf. However that will cause separated key is changed, which I can't understand how it happens.

1. Insert may cause split 2nd_page, but it needn't change separated key between 1st_leaf and 2nd_leaf, because splitting always be towards right.
2. Delete may cause removing 2nd_page, but it still needn't change separated key.

**Q2:** Even if we find a Insert Key Value in 2nd_leaf, Why do we still insert such key into 1st_leaf? Because it obviously violates the b+tree property(The keys of 1st_leaf < the keys of 2nd_leaf). The above conditions are still held except #6, since separated key is changed, so that we can find to-be-inserted-key is found in 2nd_leaf.

**Reference**

1. Mohan, C. ARIES/KVL: A Key-Value Locking Method for Concurrency Control of Multiaction Transactions Operating on B-Tree Indexes, Proc. 16th International Conference on Very Large Data Bases, Brisbane, August 1990.